# How can I accurately make this 3-level nested for-loop more efficient?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a list of users, and a list of dates. For each date there are several actions each user can take. Each action is a property in a json

```
{'type': 'feature',
  'uri': '://app.pendo.io/api/s/555555/page/testpageideabcdefg',
  'parsedUserAgent': {'name': 'Chrome',
   'version': '74.0.3729',
   'os': 'Windows'},
  'appId': -00000,
  'featureId': 'ajdkflfdjklwajfdkl;afdklafdl;adf',
  'ts': 1560178680000,
  'lastTs': 1560178731896,
  'duration': 51896}
```

I'd like my code to pull the timestamp (ts) each user has taken a specific action (emailsend_id) in the product for specified dates. That means for each user, the code would check the user record, check the date, then check for the specified feature. Then for the same user record, check for the next date in the list, etc.

I came up with this nested for loop but it timed out.

```py
for user in Users:
    queryurl= baseurl+ user+ "/history"   
    for date in Time: 
        params =  params = {"starttime": date}   
        response = requests.get(queryurl, headers = headers, params = 
        params)
        data = response.json()
        Length=len(data) 
        for pid in range(Length): 
            if data[pid]["type"]== "feature" and data[pid}["featureId"]== emailsend_id:
                StartTime = data[pid]["ts"]
                Send_date.append(StartTime)
                df_user.append(user)
                break
            else:
                continue
            break
```

How can I make this more efficient?

I tried passing a list of query URLs into a function with only 2 nested loops but that didn't work. I don't really know if this can be turned into a nested list comprehension.

Comment: syntax error `data[pid}[` <--

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] with all `import` lines. What is *df_user*?

Comment: How do you expect this to scale?  You're going to hit the server for every user, for every date/time, and the loop through all of the data being returned.  How long do you expect that to take?  What kind of load are you putting on the backend?  Are you prepared to deal with hiccups getting responses, etc.?  Also, when are you doing this--in response to another request which my cause a timeout to occur there?  The problem here is not Python code and loop efficiency, it smells like  the approach needs work.

Comment: Thanks @Parfait. Super new to this so will follow the guidelines there to make this more reproducible.

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister I am completely open to using a different approach! This is what made sense to me initially given how the data is structured and what I'm trying to accomplish, but I'd welcome any ideas on how to do this better.  I only need to capture the time stamp of the first time the event occurs so I could try breaking the loop as soon as the feature is identified...

Comment: @KC Wish I could help you more, but there really isn't enough here about what you're trying to accomplish and what resources are available to optimize this.  The goal though, would be to avoid doing lots of queries to the backend and have some way of doing the update in one fell swoop.  In this case, perhaps it's better if there was an api that said give me all instances where this feature id was affected during this start time.  In that case, you'd could get back only those entries where something really happened, rather than iterating through everything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle when `requests.get` fails and retry after a delay.